# Compass plane minimum radius

Tags: hand-tools, plane

I'm considering getting a compass plane, probably a record 020. Anyone know what is the minimum internal radius they can cut? My first use of it would be constructing a wooden wheel roughly 24inches in diameter and I suspect the inner surface would be too tight a curve.

Comment: If 020 is exact copy of Stanley 20 max and min **radius** is 20" according to Oldtooluser site, http://www.oldtooluser.com/TypeStudy/StanNo20cpTypestudy.htm

Comment: @VolframK that comment looks like an Answer to me. Or maybe we encourage the OP to snipe it for a self-answer and those sweet, sweet, SE points.

Comment: I don't know if 020 is exact copy of number 20 @jdv Also site may not be 100% reliable! Some errors so I look for confirmation

Comment: @VolframK, I couldn't find any other sources either. Have to say, looking at images with the sole at max concave adjustment it sure looks like the radius would be smaller than 50cm.

Comment: Yeah, if I had to estimate the radius of the curve from photos of various 020s I would say it was more like 10 inches than 20.

Answer (score 1):

According to oldtooluser it is 20" for the Stanley 020. As the record version is a copy of this, the same is likely to apply.

"Adjustable steel sole planes concave or convex surfaces where the minimum radius is greater than 20 inches."

From [oldtooluser.com/TypeStudy/StanNo20cpTypestudy.htm](https://oldtooluser.com/TypeStudy/StanNo20cpTypestudy.htm)

Comment: FWIW I wouldn't have thought a compass plane was a good buy just for this, they're a pretty specialist bit of kit for one, and prices can be pretty outrageous. Anyhooo, since it appears it wouldn't do it anyway it's a moot point. So, have you figured out a backup plan? How are you making the wheel rim anyway?

Comment: Considering making a fixed radius wooden compass plane to do the job. I haven't worked out the exact details of the wheel construction yet, still looking at historical pictures of early treadle lathe flywheels for inspiration.

Comment: Well that's certainly how a traditional wheelwright would have done it. I was mainly asking to see if you were going hand tools only since if you were intending to use a power router the plane would be superfluous (and ditto a bandsaw and a circle-cutting jig, to a lesser extent). Anyway, best of luck with the build. I 'made' a fixed-radius compass plane once (converted a coffin smoother) but I'm not sure if that's an option for the diameter you need. I could be visualising it poorly though, so it's an avenue worth considering just in case.